# LinearGradientBrush constructor parameters

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following code where I draw a rectangle with a linear gradient brush. However, I cannot understand the how the first two parameters of the brush constructor actually work.  I searched and all I found was that these are supposed to be the start and end point of the brush.  But how can the brush itself have a start and end point?

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(
    new Point(0, 0), new Point(40, 40), Color.Red, Color.DarkBlue);
Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
g.FillRectangle(lgb, 20, 20, 80, 80);
```

I would specifically love it if someone could tell me what would be the difference if I changed the constructor variable as follows:

```
LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(
    new Point(20, 20), new Point(60, 60), Color.Red, Color.DarkBlue);
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `LinearGradientBrush`? What specifically in the documentation for the constructor are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Have you just tried it? The difference should be pretty obvious on-screen.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Really? How is that a duplicate at all?

Comment: `BradleyDotNet` there is a difference between Duplicate and Possible Duplicate.. we've had this discussion before anyway here are some other postings to look at in regards to what you are trying and it appears you are using the constructor incorrectly https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/5d3c9f09-a38a-4d83-a727-7804dca8e5ce/lineargradientmodevertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [LinearGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(v=vs.110).aspx) paints an area with a *linear gradient*, in other words, a blending of color along a line defined by a starting point and an ending point.  The first color of the brush is used at the starting point, and the color smoothly transitions along the line such that it becomes the second color at the ending point.  Thus, by varying the endpoints, you can adjust the direction of the gradient and the distance over which the color transition occurs, even causing it to repeat if the distance is shorter than the area you are trying to fill.

You already have the code written in your question, why not try a few experiments?  I assume you have a `Panel` called `panel1` on your form with a size of at least 150 x 150 units.  For convenience, let's take your code and put it into a private method that accepts a starting point and ending point for the gradient.  For illustration purposes, we'll also add some code to draw a yellow line starting and ending at the same points as the gradient.

```
private void DrawGradient(Point startPoint, Point endPoint)
{
    LinearGradientBrush lgb = 
        new LinearGradientBrush(startPoint, endPoint, Color.Red, Color.DarkBlue);
    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    g.FillRectangle(lgb, 0, 0, 80, 80);
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Yellow, 1.5f), startPoint, endPoint);
}
```

Now we can easily call this code from somewhere convenient such as a button click handler, and pass it some points.  Here's what happens if we pass a starting point of (0, 0) and an ending point of (79, 79):

```
DrawGradient(new Point(0, 0), new Point(79, 79));
```

[image: diagonal gradient top left to bottom right]

Notice how the color transitions from red in the top left corner to blue in the bottom right along the yellow line.  What if we reverse the endpoints?

```
DrawGradient(new Point(79, 79), new Point(0, 0));
```

[image: diagonal gradient bottom right to top left]

As expected, the transition now goes in the opposite direction, with red in the lower right and blue in the upper left.  Similarly, we can make the transition go left-to-right by using endpoints for a horizontal line:

```
DrawGradient(new Point(0, 40), new Point(79, 40));
```

[image: left-to-right gradient]

The endpoints for the gradient line do not need to be on the edge of the area we are filling.  For example, if they are inside the fill area, then the gradient will repeat with a period equal to the length of the line segment.  We end up with a funky stripe effect:

```
DrawGradient(new Point(65, 25), new Point(45, 35));
```

[image: repeating gradient]

You can also place the gradient endpoints outside the fill area.  This results in a much more subtle color transition:

```
DrawGradient(new Point(0, 90), new Point(140, 40));
```

[image: gradient with endpoints outside the fill area]

Hope that helps you to understand how linear gradient brushes work.  Don't be afraid to experiment.  You can easily try these things yourself.  That is the best way to learn.

Comment: That was really helpful... so if i set the points (0,0) and (0,100) it is the same as (0,100) and (0,200)... or (0,0) and (50,50) is same as (50,50) and (100,100)... cause they r parallel..

Comment: Sort of.  Parallel lines will keep the direction of the gradient the same, but remember the gradient starts at the start point and ends at the end point.  So you could have two parallel lines with different lengths, and the gradients will look different.  For example, (10,0) and (10,50) versus (20,0) and (20,25).  You could also have lines that are parallel and have the same length, but are offset, so the gradient looks the same but is shifted as to where it starts.  For example, (10,10) and (10,50) versus (20,20) and (20,60).  (continued)

Comment: But you are right that there are multiple sets of starting and ending points that result in the same exact gradient result.